# WinHttpSendRequest and HTTPS on Windows XP

Tags: c++, windows, windows-xp, winhttp

OS: Windows XP SP3. Application should download the picture from the website via **https** protocol. As a result, `WinHttpSendRequest` returns an error -2146893018. Here is the code snippet:

```
hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest(hConnect, L"GET", Path, Protocol, 0, 0, WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE);

    if(hRequest){
        bResults = WinHttpSendRequest(hRequest, WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS, 0,
                                      WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA, 0, 0, 0);
    ...
    }
```

This problem is only on WinXP. On Windows 7 - everything works fine.

But if try to download another image from another website via **http** protocol (replacing WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE with 0), then everything works fine.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the server is using TLS 1.2 256-bit encryption. Try to install KB968730 and KB3055973 updates, but they adds only partial support for TLS 1.2.

Windows XP is dead and this is truth. Now it is not a internet-compatible OS.